# How to build a JavaScript callback queue and execute it having a final callback

Tags: javascript, animation, callback, promise, queue

I am doing some animations or cartoon-like things with javascript. The animation has some scripts that execute some instructions in sequence like drawing things on the canvas and playing sounds. Some scripts have to be executed multiple times. So to execute script 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (3 times) and then 5 to make a complete animation sequence. My code looks like this:

```
        var player = new TTMPlayer(resource["MJJOG.TTM"], ctx);
        player.playscript(0, function () {
            player.playscript(1, function () {
                player.playscript(2, function () {
                    player.playscript(3, function () {
                        player.playscript(4, function () {
                            player.playscript(4, function () {
                                player.playscript(4, function () {
                                    player.playscript(5, function () {
                                        alert("done");
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        });
```

The TTMPlayer is loaded with all the different scripted sequences. The "playscript" functions process all drawing routines (with delays etc) and when one script is done it calls the callback function that is just another playscript call that will play the next script in sequence.
I would like to be able to make an array or queue of scripts and have it execute more simple like this:

```
player.playscripts([0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5], function () { alert("done"); }));
```

But how can I implement this in javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use an array containing the numbers you want to call `playscript` with, then iterate over the array and `await` a `Promise` that resolves when the `playscript` callback is called:

```
(async () => {
  const player = new TTMPlayer(resource["MJJOG.TTM"], ctx);
  const playProm = num => new Promise(resolve, () => {
    player.playscript(num, resolve);
  });
  const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    await playProm(arr[i]);
  }
  console.log('done');
})();
```

Another option would be to use `reduceRight`:

```
const player = new TTMPlayer(resource["MJJOG.TTM"], ctx);
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,4,4,5];
const firstFn = arr.reduceRight(
  (nextCallback, num) => () => player.playscript(num, nextCallback),
  () => console.log('done')
);
firstFn();
```

Comment: I had absolutely no knowledge that async await had been implemented in JavaScript. This is great, thanks.